# Rule of thumb for tmp_table_size and max_heap_table_size MySQL properties

Tags: mysql, performance, join, sorting

The title pretty much sums up the question itself: Is there a rule of thumb regarding the values for `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` MySQL properties?

I've had a serious performance degradation which was caused by the fact MySQL used disk space to filesort a JOIN result.

Increasing `tmp_table_size` and `max_heap_table_size` to 3G solved the issue but this is more of a trial and error approach.

Is there a more solid way to calculate an appropriate value for these two?

Answer (score 10):

I recommend a simple 1% of memory for each of those.

- `max_heap_table_size` is the limit on a `ENGINE=MEMORY` table you `CREATE`.  Not many people use that engine, if you do, set the max size just before doing the create.
- `LEAST(max_heap_table_size, tmp_table_size)` is the cap on how big to let certain implicit temp tables to get.  These are tables used inside `SELECTs` (etc) to handle `GROUP BY`, `ORDER BY`, subqueries, etc.

Since those temp tables can be created by every connection, and possibly multiple temp tables per query, 1% of RAM is a rather "safe" limit.  When MySQL runs out of RAM, the OS swaps things -- Swapping MySQL is *terrible* for performance.

Also, in setting these too large, you are stealing RAM from other uses (eg, buffer_pool), thereby potentially slowing down all queries.

Other [*Rules of Thumb*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/ricksrots)

See also `SQL_BIG_RESULT`.

Comment: 1% of RAM is detrimental for the performance of the queries. Testing this setting made my queries take more than quadruple the time than before. Fortunately enough, there aren't many connections to the database when these queries are executed so I do enjoy the luxury of increasing these to around 2G...

Comment: @Niko - There may be ways to make the query run with with a smaller tmp table.  If you like, start a new Question with the query, its `EXPLAIN` and `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 5):

It may be tempting to increase `tmp_table_size` (and its dependency,  `max_heap_table_size` IF MEMORY is used for temporary memory engines- newest versions use InnoDB instead) to as long as possible. After all, if you run the same query with a larger table size, it will likely be faster!

However, there are 2 reasons to not do that, that I can think of:

- If the temporary table is going to be huge, you are going to waste time inserting rows to memory, and then copy it to disk, then continue inserting rows. Depending on the query, you may find that writing to disk as soon as possible may be faster.
- While setting up large buffers may seem like a good idea, there is not infinite memory- so if every query/connection is going to take 3G of memory, you may run out of it, and start writing to disk anyway due to virtual memory swapping (which will likely either end up crashing MySQL due to Out of Memory errors or be impossibly slow).

Now, if you are just running a single query and not several in conccurency (so you will not have those issues), and it works for you to be much faster, feel free to increase it (but probably you may want to change it for the session only so it doesn't affect other queries that could get those regressions I mentioned).

To calculate a good value, chose the max amount of memory you would want your query to take (note you will also need memory for the `join_buffer_size`. `sort_buffer_size`, `read_buffer_size`, and other buffers) or the largest temporary table you would generate, whatever is smaller.

You can use the `Created_tmp_disk_tables` and `Created_tmp_tables` variables to know how many temporary tables and temporary tables on disk you are creating at global scope (although some will be unavoidable- for example, heap tables do not allow blobs, and some queries will always need temporary tables, no matter the indexing).